# How i can paginate one Lucid Orm Relationship?

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

I have this query that makes a relationship, so i need to paginate.

I try:

```
async show({ request }){
    const { page, pageSize } = request.get();
    const book = await Book.find(request.params.id)
    await book.paginate(page, pageSize)
    await book.load('book_unit_questions')
    const questions = book.getRelated('book_unit_questions')
    return questions
}
```

But i get:

> error: {message: "book.paginate is not a function", name: "TypeError",
>   status: 500,…}

Also tried:

```
async show({ request }){
    const { page, pageSize } = request.get();
    const book = await Book.query().where('id', request.params.id).with('book_unit_questions').paginate(page,pageSize)
    const questions = book.getRelated('book_unit_questions')
    return questions
}
```

But this way i get:

> {error: {message: "book.getRelated is not a function", name:
>   "TypeError", status: 500,…}}